# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Can't invoke Razor Page from custom middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to create custom exception handling middlware. similar to -> app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"). I will log the error in middleware and then i want invoke Error page.
The problem is, when i do redirect then IExceptionHandlerFeature object from context.Features.Get() is NULL.
Seems that context exceptions are cleared when Razorpage is executed. In the original middleware it somehow works.

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Serilog Global exception logger");
            logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {ex}");
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        context.Response.Redirect("/ErrorHandling/Error");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }


}
```

Here is my Razor Error Page model

```
 [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    private ILogger<ErrorModel> _logger;
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionPath { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }

    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);

    public ErrorModel(ILogger<ErrorModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void OnGet(string executionPath)
    {
        var httpCtx = HttpContext;

        var exceptionDetails = httpCtx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        if (exceptionDetails != null)
        {
            _logger.LogError(httpCtx.Response.StatusCode, exceptionDetails.Error, exceptionDetails.Error.Message);

            //Add data for view
            ExceptionPath = exceptionDetails.Path;
            ExceptionMessage = "An unexpected fault happened. Try again later.";

        }

        RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;

    }
}
```

After redirection httpCtx.Features.Get() should return IExceptionHandlerPathFeature  object, but it returns NULL

Comment: What do you mean `when i do redirect then context.Features.Get() is lost`,could you tell how to reproduce  your problem and what would  you like to get in the error page?

Comment: I mean, when use  -> context.Response.Redirect("/ErrorHandling/Error") in my middleware then after redirection httpCtx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>() in Error Razor page model is null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code of [ExceptionHandlerMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5e575a3e64254932c1fd4937041a4e7426afcde4/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) and [ExceptionHandlerExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/28157e62597bf0e043bc7e937e44c5ec81946b83/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerExtensions.cs), you need to use rewrite instead of redirect.

Below is simplified code of custom ExceptionMiddleware

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    public ExceptionMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory
    )
    {
        _next = next;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Serilog Global exception logger");
            logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {ex}");
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }

    }


    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        PathString originalPath = context.Request.Path;
        context.Request.Path = "/Error";
        try
        {
            var exceptionHandlerFeature = new ExceptionHandlerFeature()
            {
                Error = ex,
                Path = originalPath.Value,
            };
            context.Features.Set<IExceptionHandlerFeature>(exceptionHandlerFeature);
            context.Features.Set<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>(exceptionHandlerFeature);
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            await _next(context);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Request.Path = originalPath;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Andres Sööt Great.Could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have resolved the problem?